# Inconsistent collision issues in Unity Physics scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im having an issue where an object isnt registering collision properly when it hits a collider head on.
The object will phase into the collider before popping out
[Broken Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUmDy.gif)

It should work like this all the time
[Working Exaample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STa1a.gif)
But it only does when the object comes at an angle

The Rigidbody is moved using Rigidbody.moveposition so it should be interacting with the physics scene properly, my guess is that there is some way to increase the resistance to clipping, but I havent found any setting like that

Comment: I would check that the colliders are correctly positioned in the scene and that the rigidbody is handled in the `FixedUpdate`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Rigidbody.moveposition doesn't actually check for collisions when moving. You could try moving the cube using Rigidbody.velocity instead. If that's not an option, I recon you would have to check every frame if you went through a collider.

You can check to see if you went through a collider by saving your position at the end of the frame, and next frame shooting a ray from your current position to your last frame position something like this:

```
Vector3 lastFramePosition;

void Update()
{
    if (lastFramePosition != null && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.position - lastFramePosition))
    {
        transform.position = lastFramePosition;
    }

    // stuff

    lastFramePosition = transform.position;
}
```

Comment: However, I would advise against this method since doing an extra raycast every frame can be taxing on the pc. So unless not possible, use Rigidbody.velocity instead.